# Mapbox markers move when zooming in/out

Tags: javascript, html, css, mapbox

I'm working on MapBoxgl and I want to add the location of a restaurant as a marker.

Here is my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Com Viet</title>

    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/e3c287111d.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- CSS Stylesheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Styles/style.css">

    <!-- Google Fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:500,700|Roboto+Condensed:300,400,600" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Mapbox API -->
    <script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.8.1/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
    <link href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.8.1/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <!-- Mapbox Geocode -->
    <script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/plugins/mapbox-gl-geocoder/v4.2.0/mapbox-gl-geocoder.min.js'></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/plugins/mapbox-gl-geocoder/v4.2.0/mapbox-gl-geocoder.css' type='text/css'/>
</head>

<body>

    <section id="map">
        <h1>Find Us</h1>

    </section>

    <script src="app.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

This is app.js:

```
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoibWlvY2h1bmc3IiwiYSI6ImNrOG13cXoxbDA2c2UzbW1lcm1iZWZ5NnEifQ.5nuyV8naVrjogYKyx_TFzw';



const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map', //appears in the container with the ID map
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
    center: [-0.1103, 51.5082], // Starting position [lng, lat]
    zoom: 11.89, // [Starting zoom]


});

// Custom Marker

var marker = new mapboxgl.Marker() // initialize a new marker
    .setLngLat([-0.1103, 51.5082]) // Marker [lng, lat] coordinates
    .addTo(map); // Add the marker to the map

// Geocode

var geocoder = new MapboxGeocoder({ // Initialize the geocoder
    accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken, // Set the access token
    mapboxgl: mapboxgl, // Set the mapbox-gl instance
    marker: false, // Do not use the default marker style
    placeholder: '',
    proximity: {
        longitude: -0.1103,
        latitude: 51.5082
    }
});

// Add the geocoder to the map
map.addControl(geocoder);
```

The CSS is:

```
#map {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
}
```

```js
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoibWlvY2h1bmc3IiwiYSI6ImNrOG13cXoxbDA2c2UzbW1lcm1iZWZ5NnEifQ.5nuyV8naVrjogYKyx_TFzw';



const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map', //appears in the container with the ID map
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
    center: [-0.1103, 51.5082], // Starting position [lng, lat]
    zoom: 11.89, // [Starting zoom]


});

// Custom Marker

var marker = new mapboxgl.Marker() // initialize a new marker
    .setLngLat([-0.1103, 51.5082]) // Marker [lng, lat] coordinates
    .addTo(map); // Add the marker to the map

// Geocode

var geocoder = new MapboxGeocoder({ // Initialize the geocoder
    accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken, // Set the access token
    mapboxgl: mapboxgl, // Set the mapbox-gl instance
    marker: false, // Do not use the default marker style
    placeholder: '',
    proximity: {
        longitude: -0.1103,
        latitude: 51.5082
    }
});

// Add the geocoder to the map
map.addControl(geocoder);
```

```css
#map {
 width: 100%;
 height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Com Viet</title>

    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/e3c287111d.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- CSS Stylesheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Styles/style.css">

    <!-- Google Fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:500,700|Roboto+Condensed:300,400,600" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Mapbox API -->
    <script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.8.1/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
    <link href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.8.1/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <!-- Mapbox Geocode -->
    <script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/plugins/mapbox-gl-geocoder/v4.2.0/mapbox-gl-geocoder.min.js'></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/plugins/mapbox-gl-geocoder/v4.2.0/mapbox-gl-geocoder.css' type='text/css'/>
</head>

<body>

 

    <section id="map">
        <h1>Find Us</h1>
        
    </section>



    <script src="app.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

[This is the first picture before zooming in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9dqO.jpg)
[This is the second picture after zooming in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vr8ET.jpg)

I'm not sure what is causing the problem. Also the search box somehow seems to be above the map instead of inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is currently adding the [marker](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#marker) to a map container which includes both the map and a heading "Find Us." This means the location is offset by the height of the heading.

```
<section id="map">
    <h1>Find Us</h1>
</section>
```

To fix this you should move the map to its own `<div>` like this:

```
<section id="container">
  <h1>Find Us</h1>
  <div id="map"></div>
</section>
```

And your full code should look something like this:

```js
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoibWlvY2h1bmc3IiwiYSI6ImNrOG13cXoxbDA2c2UzbW1lcm1iZWZ5NnEifQ.5nuyV8naVrjogYKyx_TFzw';



const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map', //appears in the container with the ID map
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
    center: [-0.1103, 51.5082], // Starting position [lng, lat]
    zoom: 11.89, // [Starting zoom]


});

// Custom Marker

var marker = new mapboxgl.Marker() // initialize a new marker
    .setLngLat([-0.1103, 51.5082]) // Marker [lng, lat] coordinates
    .addTo(map); // Add the marker to the map

// Geocode

var geocoder = new MapboxGeocoder({ // Initialize the geocoder
    accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken, // Set the access token
    mapboxgl: mapboxgl, // Set the mapbox-gl instance
    marker: false, // Do not use the default marker style
    placeholder: '',
    proximity: {
        longitude: -0.1103,
        latitude: 51.5082
    }
});

// Add the geocoder to the map
map.addControl(geocoder);
```

```css
#map {
 width: 100%;
 height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Com Viet</title>

    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/e3c287111d.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- CSS Stylesheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Styles/style.css">

    <!-- Google Fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:500,700|Roboto+Condensed:300,400,600" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Mapbox API -->
    <script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.8.1/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
    <link href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.8.1/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <!-- Mapbox Geocode -->
    <script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/plugins/mapbox-gl-geocoder/v4.2.0/mapbox-gl-geocoder.min.js'></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/plugins/mapbox-gl-geocoder/v4.2.0/mapbox-gl-geocoder.css' type='text/css'/>
</head>

<body>

 

<section id="container">
  <h1>Find Us</h1>
  <div id="map"></div>
</section>



    <script src="app.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Disclaimer: I work at Mapbox

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Patrick's answer, a problem I ran into was I was setting the mapbox width and height programmatically in the code to `100vh`:

```
  dom: HTMLElement = this.elementRef.nativeElement;
  elements = dom.querySelectorAll('.mapboxgl-canvas');
  elements[0]['style']['height'] = '100vh';
```

I am using Angular, so your code for setting height & width might be different. When I switched it from `100vh` to `100%` this problem went away.